# Drop Duplicates in a DataFrame if Timestamps are Close, but not Identical

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

Imagine that I've got the following DataFrame

```
            A        | B | C | D
 -------------------------------
 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 1
 2000-01-01 00:04:30 | 1 | 2 | 2
 2000-01-01 00:04:30 | 2 | 3 | 3
 2000-01-02 00:00:00 | 1 | 4 | 4
```

And I want to drop rows where `B` are equal, and the values in `A` are "close". Say, withing five minutes of each other. So in this case the first two rows, but keep the last two.

So, instead of doing `df.dropna(subset=['A', 'B'], inplace=True, keep=False)`, I'd like something that's more like `df.dropna(subset=['A', 'B'], inplace=True, keep=False, func={'A': some_func})`. With

```
def some_func(ts1, ts2):
    delta = ts1 - ts2
    return abs(delta.total_seconds()) >= 5 * 60
```

Is there a way to do this in Pandas?

Comment: if you have a 3rd reading which is within 5 minutes of the 2nd, but greater than 5 minutes from the first, what happens to that?

Comment: Honestly, I hadn't considered that. In my particular case the number of duplicates should be so few that that never actually happens. On the off chance that it did my preferred behaviour would be to drop the two with the closest timestamps, but could live with something else.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, please make sure the code works for your actual case... if not, let me know, include an example of your data where it fails along with expected output so it can be debugged. Alternatively, you can open another question. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
m = df.groupby('B').A.apply(lambda x: x.diff().dt.seconds < 300)
m2 = df.B.duplicated(keep=False) & (m | m.shift(-1))
df[~m2]
                    A  B  C  D
2 2000-01-01 00:04:30  2  3  3
3 2000-01-02 00:00:00  1  4  4
```

---

**Details**

`m` gets a mask of all rows within 5 minutes of each other.

```
m

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

`m2` is the final mask of all items that must be dropped.

```
m2

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

I break down the steps ...And you can test with your real data to see whether it works or not ..

```
df['dropme']=df.A.diff().shift(-1).dt.seconds/60
df['dropme2']=df.A
df.loc[df.dropme<=5,'dropme2']=1
df.drop_duplicates(['dropme2'],keep=False).drop(['dropme','dropme2'],axis=1)
Out[553]: 
                    A  B  C  D
2 2000-01-01 00:04:30  2  3  3
3 2000-01-02 00:00:00  1  4  4
```

Answer (score 0):

write a function that accepts a data frame, calculates the delta between two successive timestamps, and return the filtered dataframe. Then groupby & apply.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# this one preserves 1 row from two or more closeby rows.
def filter_window(df):
    df['filt'] = (df.A - df.A.shift(1)) / datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
    df['filt'] = df.filt.fillna(10.0)
    df = df[(df.filt > 5.0) | pd.isnull(df.filt)]
    return df[['A', 'C', 'D']]

df2 = df.groupby('B').apply(filter_window).reset_index()

# With your sample dataset, this is the output of df2

                      A     B   C   D
0   2000-01-01 00:00:00     1   1   1
1   2000-01-02 00:00:00     1   4   4
2   2000-01-01 00:04:30     2   3   3

# this one drops all closeby rows.
def filter_window2(df):
    df['filt'] = (df.A - df.A.shift(1)) / datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
    df['filt2'] = (df.A.shift(-1) - df.A) / datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
    df['filt'] = df.filt.fillna(df.filt2)
    df = df[(df.filt > 5.0) | pd.isnull(df.filt)]
    return df[['A', 'C', 'D']]

df3 = df.groupby('B').apply(filter_window2).reset_index()

# With your sample dataset, this is the output of df3

                      A     B   C   D
0   2000-01-02 00:00:00     1   4   4
1   2000-01-01 00:04:30     2   3   3
```